# Setting up CPLEX on Windows Visual Studio 2022 (For C++ use)

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I am a beginner with IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio.

So I want to use C++ (via Visual Studio) to use CPLEX. Can you please help walk me through the process of setting up CPLEX on Visual C++ 2022? I'm still looking for the 2022 version to be implemented, but without success.

Please help.

Best regards.

Comment: Seems like your question wants someone to create or link to a tutorial on how to setup some library. This request is off-topic at StackOverflow. An on-topic question would be you showing what you have tried and explain what happened and then ask 1 question about a problem you can demonstrate.

Comment: These [instructions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.1?topic=cplex-setting-up-windows) seem reasonable / not very difficult. What happened when you tried them?